I am adding free trials on subscription in google play console but it is not showing when i purchae subscription with even with new user
.I have a app in flutter.I have two plans Monthly and yearly and i added offers on both for free trials but this doesn't show on subscription bottom sheet. I have searched everywhere but not found solution.
I have added offers for new user but it doesn't work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I added free trial in both plans but it doesn't show free trial when I am purchasing plan for a new user.
